# Unable to load the "PHP Email Form" Library

Tags: php, forms, contacts

For some reason, my PHP Form doesn't work, when someone presses send message button this error pops out "Unable to load the "PHP Email Form" Library". I don't know what the problem is.

This is contact.php

```
<?php

    $receiving_email_address = 'myemailadress';
    
      if( file_exists($php_email_form = '../assets/vendor/php-email-form/php-email-form.php' )) {
        include( $php_email_form );
      } else {
        die( 'Coming Soon!');
      }
    
      $contact = new PHP_Email_Form;
      $contact->ajax = true;
      
      $contact->to = $receiving_email_address;
      $contact->from_name = $_POST['name'];
      $contact->from_email = $_POST['email'];
      $contact->subject = $_POST['subject'];
    
      // Uncomment below code if you want to use SMTP to send emails. You need to enter your correct SMTP credentials
      /*
      $contact->smtp = array(
        'host' => 'example.com',
        'username' => 'example',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'port' => '587'
      );
      */
    
      $contact->add_message( $_POST['name'], 'From');
      $contact->add_message( $_POST['email'], 'Email');
      $contact->add_message( $_POST['message'], 'Message', 10);
    
      echo $contact->send();
    ?>
```

This is index.html

```
 <div class="form">
              <form action="forms/contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="my-3">
                  <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                  <div class="error-message"></div>
                  <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

Anf for some reason some kind of a error log file came up in the folder that says:

```
[19-Nov-2021 13:49:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHP_Email_Form' not found in /home/domain/public_html/forms/contact.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/domain/public_html/forms/contact.php on line 16
[19-Nov-2021 13:49:32 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHP_Email_Form' not found in /home/domain/public_html/forms/contact.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/domain/public_html/forms/contact.php on line 16
```

I guess I should add this home/domain/public.html/froms/contact.php on line 16 but I don't know how to do that properly apparently.

Comment: Wouldn't you get `'Coming Soon!'` there?

Comment: Please share more detais. Line 16 in the given code should not trigger that error. What did you try to resolve it? Did you check whether the `include` is really executed? Whether the included file really contains the class you are looking for?

Comment: Please check the 'php-email-form.php' is present your folder. I m sure you are using BOOTSTRAPMADE free template thats why this file is missing. You may use PHP's mail()
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Answer (score 2):

Or you can write own sender. Something like this.

contact.php

```
$to = 'yourmail@yourdomain.ltd';
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$from = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$subject = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'subject', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

if (filter_var($from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $headers = ['From' => ($name?"<$name> ":'').$from,
            'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
           ];

    mail($to, $subject, $message."\r\n\r\nfrom: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $headers);
    die('OK');
    
} else {
    die('Invalid address');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the code is searching for a file "php-email-form.php" in this particular directory/folder,-> ../assets/vendor/php-email-form/php-email-form.php,
check if the required php is present there, otherwise you need to create one and place it there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a variable in `file_exists()`. Use

```
if( file_exists('../assets/vendor/php-email-form/php-email-form.php')) {
    include('../assets/vendor/php-email-form/php-email-form.php');
} else {
    die( 'Coming Soon!');
}
```

or

```
$php_email_form = '../assets/vendor/php-email-form/php-email-form.php';
if(file_exists($php_email_form)) {
    include($php_email_form);
} else {
    die('Coming Soon!');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately this doesnt work :/

Comment: Doesn't work as in the file isn't included? That _should_ work if the file exists. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Comment: Ok, that's for the second version, I forgot the ending `;` - my fault. Did you try the first version too then?

Answer (score 0):

you are using the free template and the PHP Form
requires the "PHP Email Form" library and
the "PHP Email Form" library is available only in the pro version of the template.

you must to buy the pro version template

if you don't want to buy you must create your own php code

Comment: What do you mean by "free template"? There are tons of tutorials about a  "PHP Email Form library", which one do you refer to?

Comment: That's not it, I fixed the problem a long time ago, I forgot what I did honestly :D